# Obtain customer collection with filtered addresses in Eloquent

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-collection

I have this two models:

```
   customers(id,firstname,lastname,phone)
   addresses(id,province_id,address,customer_id)
```

With relation:

```
 class Customer extends Model
 {

     public function addresses()
     {
         return $this->hasMany(Address::class);
     }
 }


 public function customer()
     {
         return $this->belongsTo(Customer::class,'customer_id');
     }
```

And I'm trying to obtain `customers with address in certain city`

```
  return new CustomerCollection(Customer::has('addresses')
                       ->with(array('addresses' => function($q) use ($field)
                        {
                          $q->where('province_id','like',$field)->get();

                        }))->orderBy('id','DESC')->paginate(100));
```

Result is almost fine, I obtain the collection with all customers (bad) when I only need customers with address in province given, but addresses array only contain data for addresses in the province given.

[image]

What's wrong? How Can remove from result the customer without address in province?

Comment: Try this :
$q->where('province_id','like','%'.$field.'%')->get();

Comment: Result is the same. addresses array is sended but empty

Comment: I have checked and addresses array is not empty. But customer collection is with all customers (bad) and I only get addresses with province_id given. I have updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this, if you not gonna provide a province_id in your query then it will escape the condition and get you all customer with there address and if you provide `province_id` you will get the only customer that lives in the `provind_id`

```
Customer::query()->when($province_id,function($query){
            $query->whereHas('addresses', function($query) use($province_id){
                $query->where('province_id', $province_id);
            }); 
        })
        ->with('addresses')
        ->get();
```

**Update:**

```
class Customer extends Model
{
   
    public function scopeFilterByProvince($query, $provinceId = null)
    {
        return $query->when($province_id,function($query){
            $query->whereHas('addresses', function($query) use($province_id){
                $query->where('province_id', $province_id);
            }); 

       // if you pass name of province use this
       return $query->when($province,function($query){
            $query->whereHas('addresses', function($query) use($province){
                $query->whereHas('province', function($q) use($province){
                   $q->where('name', 'like', '%{$province}%');
               });
            }); 
    }
}
```

then controller or ur repo

```
Customer::filterByProvince($request->get('province_id'))
        ->with('addresses')
        ->get();
```

Comment: it will be good to add this `when()` in a [local scope](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#local-scopes) so you use it everywhere u need it and when call you use only `Customer::filterProvince($province_id)->with('addresses')->...`

Comment: Doesn't work. But your answer looks good. I will try to modify.

Comment: I tried local scope too. But only works when need only data customer. data adresses is in another table and cannot get

Comment: I assume you're getting `$province_id` from `$request->get('province_id ')` , if `$province_id` is `null` it will escape the condition

Comment: I get province_id fine. But customer collection get all customers, and only get address info for addresses in this province. Rest of address info (for the rest of customers) is empty

Comment: if province is null you will get all customers but not necessarily have addresses but if province_id isn't null you will get only customers that has an address with province_id.. but you can playground this code to customize it as you need.. I have no similar data to test on

Comment: I needed some changes in ur code but you help a lot. Very thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
    Customer::with('addresses')->whereHas('addresses', function ($q) use ($field) {
        return $q->where('province_id', 'like', '%'.$field.'%');
    })
```

You don't need to use `get()` inside the nested query of the relation. Also `like` syntax was not correct in your question. Try above solution

Comment: This option only send Customers data but any information about addresses. Also addresses array now is not sended

Comment: For this way I get all customers with their addresses: 

`return new CustomerCollection(Customer::with('addresses')->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate(500));`

But now I need same solution & structure but on with certain provinces

Comment: you can use with('addresses') as well if you want to return this collection. I editted my answer.